# Extra slashes on json response

Tags: php, json, rest, yii2

On database: `{ "email", "color" }`

But when I try to output it using `application/json' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON`, the string contains extra slashes

```
[
      "Verify",
      "{ \"email\", \"color\" }"
    ]
```

I know that I can sort of use the `replace()` but can someone enlighten me on this scenario?

Comment: the data already in json, so just try to show in text

Comment: It doesn't contain "extra slashes", the database content has been encoded as a JSON string.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams so the best way for me to get the email and color string is to somehow parse it?

Comment: That depends on how it is stored in the database. If it is a e.g. PostgreSQL array then there should be a mechanism in place for getting it as an array.

Answer (score 1):

@webDav almost has the correct answer.

It appears you are incorporating the data from the database into another data structure.  So you will need to parse the JSON from the database first, then include that data in your data before encoding again.

You are not retrieving raw string (similar to JSON) from the DB, but it is a string that needs to be converted to JSON in order to have meaning.

Answer (score 1):

the encode add the slashes for prevent improper quotes sequence that break the corret use of content

whitout slashes you have in yoru case

```
  "{ "email", "color" }"  // that is not correctly formateed
```

you have already quote around you value in database..  and you data are already in  json format so so you could use without encode

Comment: `{"email", "color"}` is not valid JSON.

Comment: .@IgnacioVazquez-Abrams   thanks  ... refuse removed

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to parse the non-JSON to an object then incorporate it and re-encode as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are trying to encode an already json encoded data.

As a results it escapes the characters.

You have 2 options:

1. Do not format it to JSON again
2. Decode the data with `json_decode()` before return

If you need to append or combine that json data, then #2 is your only option

Comment: solved my problem. thanks.